# WPF wmv/mpg files skipping and jumping

Tags: wpf, mediaplayback

I am trying to play some WMV/MPG files using the MediaElement control and for some reason, the video files jump and skip while they are playing.

I have played them on their own, outside of the WPF application and they seem to play ok, so why might this be?

I do scale them so that they are smaller, could that be an issue?

Also, if you think that its a codec issue, can I download an application to see what type on encoding it has? I do have 1 (and only one) video file that plays perfectly, so I would want to mimic that one if possible.

EDIT: I just tried to use one of the Vista videos that sit in the "Sample Videos" folder and it is also jumpy... I have no idea why. Its a WMV file.

For some reason, I can get one video file to play ok, which is a MPG file (actually it only skips once, and its hard to notice), curious that its an MPG file thouh..

Thanks a lot!
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in a flurry of external libraries and articles I came across this codeplex library:

http://www.codeplex.com/WPFMediaKit

Which has a control the is a replacement for the MediaElement control, called **MediaUriElement**, I hot-swapped the WPF MediaElement control with this one and all the media issues went away! It even has a Loop flag so you dont have to reset the media Position property when the media ends!

Its only early days of testing, but so far so good :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the full reason why this might be happening, but I do have a suggestion to help you troubleshoot:
If you are looking for in depth information about a media file, I would recommend [downloading VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) - I've found it to have very good metadata viewable relatively easily. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah VLC is the first place I went, thanks, I thought there might be a different one out there as it wasnt really helping me out